# How to use latest MapBox Studio style

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I apologize if this is an obvious question, but I have tileset (vector layer) id "fedex1.9iw8f8pj" and I'm trying to use it in a style.

For style, see

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/fedex1/cimjgbe1i0087g4nskorn50pd.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZmVkZXgxIiwiYSI6ImNpam5jZXZvczAwZnd0b201ajhybXE0OW8ifQ.IumX7VWjU71UjEsKTN4bdw#20/40.669883372111315/-73.89544420452764/0

I do not see the "parking-regulation-shapefile" layer.

See the tileset:

[image: The image shows the x and y locations]

*The image shows the x and y locations*

Yet in the style I do not see the x and y locations:

[image]

Why is there no zoom level here?:

[image]

When I "select data" in the style I see:

[image]

I'd like to show the x,y points and possibly the SIGNDESC1 at a certain zoom level.

(I assume it is ok to show the access token since it is in the javascript source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a console error when viewing your style:

```
mapbox-gl.js:170 Error: Source layer "Parking_regulation_Shapefile" does not exist on source "composite" as specified by style layer "parking-regulation-shapefile"
```

Your style specifies a source layer of `Parking_regulation_Shapefile` while your tileset only provides a source layer of `Parking_regulation_Shapefile_enh`.

This detail ought to be taken care of by Mapbox Studio. Did you change the tileset after creating the style? Does removing and re-adding the source for the layer fix the problem? If neither of those help, let me know!

Comment: Thanks very much.  Re-adding the source did it.  And yes when I uploaded the file the second time, I renamed the file and that caused the tileset to change, even though I replaced the existing one.  (i believe)  It works now!